# change of variable in contour(complex) integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there the theorem about change of variable in contour integral? I just read about translation rule, but I want to know more like real case. For example,when I compute this,
$\int_C^\ \frac{2z} {z^4 +6z^2 +1}  dz $ where $C(t) = e^{it}, t \in [0,2\pi]$

putting $w = f(z) = z^2$ then $dw=2zdz$ and the contour $f(C)$ will describe two rounds with radius 1, at centor 0 and same direction with $C$. So I guess $\int_C^\ \frac{2z} {z^4 +6z^2 +1}  dz = \frac{1}{2}\int_{f(C)} \frac{1}{w^2+6w+1}dw$ and it is true. I want to know general case.

Comment: Even though some integration methods are not stated as theorems in most text books, they still carry over complex variable. For example, integration by parts and some substitution are used for some integrals. The key is to remember that substitution are trated as mapping/transformations in the complex plane, so the curve is also changing (as you correctly analized in your problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if $\zeta$ is holomorphic on the contour $C$ and $f$ is continuous on $\zeta(C),$ then
$$
\int_{\zeta(C)} f(\zeta)\,\mathrm{d}\zeta = \int_C f(\zeta(z))\zeta'(z)\,\mathrm{d}z.
$$
So formally $\mathrm{d}\zeta = \zeta'(z)\mathrm{d}z$.

You can prove this by using a parameterisation of the curves and the chain rule.

Comment: Note that in your example, the circle is crossed twice. So a parametrisation should be like $\exp(it)$ for $t \in [0,4\pi]$ (this will cancel the $1/2$ in your statement).

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it soon :)

Comment: Let me just add that a more natural parameterisation would be $\exp(2it), t \in [0,2\pi].$